# Nested Sequence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem in Kolmogorov's real analysis textbook.

> By the diameter of a subset $A$ of a metric space $R$ is meant the number
>   \begin{equation*}
> d(A) = \sup\limits_{x, y \in A} \rho(x,y).
> \end{equation*}
>   Suppose $R$ is complete, and let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of closed subsets of $R$ nested in the sense that
>   $$
> A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \cdots A_n \supset \cdots.
> $$
>   Suppose further that 
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(A_n) = 0.
> $$
>   Prove that the intersection $\bigcap\limits_{n =1}^{\infty} A_n$ is nonempty.

Here is my best attempt at a proof, trying to incorporate the assumption that $R$ is complete.

> Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of closed, nested subsets of $R$ such that $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \cdots$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(A_n) = 0$.
>
> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, pick $x_n \in A_n$, constructing the sequence $\{x_n\}$. Since $A_n \subset R$ for all $n$, $x_n \subset R$ for any $n$.
>
> Observe that $A_m \subset A_j$ implies that $\sup A_m \leq \sup A_j$. Similarly, if $A_m \subset A_j$, we have $\sup_{x, y \in A_m} \rho(x,y) \leq \sup_{x,y \in A_j} \rho(x,y)$, so $d(A_m) \leq d(A_j)$. Furthermore, since $d(A_n) \to 0$, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|d(A_n)| < \epsilon$.
>
> We will prove that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. Let $\epsilon > 0$. By drawing on convergence of $d(A_n)$ to $0$, choose $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|d(A_n)| < \epsilon$. For any $m, n > N$, in which case $x \in A_m$ and $x \in A_n$, have $A_m, A_n \subset A_N$. Without loss of generality, we can take $m > n$. (If $m = n$, then $|x_m - x_n| = 0 < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and the result is proved.) This implies that $A_m \subset A_n$, so $x_m \in A_m$ implies that $x_m \in A_n$. We have: 
>   \begin{align*}
> \rho(x_m, x_n) & \leq \sup_{x, y \in A_n} \rho(x, y) & & \text{Definition of supremum} \\
> & \leq \sup_{x,y \in A_N} \rho(x,y) & & \text{Since $A_n \subset A_N$} \\
> & = d(A_N) & & \text{Definition} \\
> & \leq |d(A_N)| & & \text{Definition of absolute value} \\
> & < \epsilon & & \text{Choice of $N$ since $d(A_N) \to 0$}
> \end{align*}
>   Thus, $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $R$. Since $R$ is a complete space, $\{x_n\} \to x \in R$.
>
> Since this holds for an arbitrary $n$, it holds for all $n$. Thus, any such sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. But $\{x_n\} \in A_n$, and $A_n$ is closed, so $x \in A_n$, as closed sets contain all of their limit points. Thus, $x \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

I have some additional questions on this proof:

1. I am unsure of whether I should be using the "absolute value" metric in my proof that $x_n$ is Cauchy, particularly because I do not use this when writing the proof that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. Have I sacrificed generality in doing this?
2. The last paragraph of the proof is not completely clear to me or, at the very least, I am unsure completely on how to formalize it. Some help with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof in general is absolutely fine, I have juts a couple of comments for the streamlining of the proof.

- First of all, the diameter of a set is always non-negative, so the absolute value signs are not necessary. (Positive side effect, no generality was sacrificed, just efficiency. :-))
- Second, the sentence "Observe that $A_m \subset A_j$ implies that $\sup A_m \leq \sup A_j$." is nonsensical as $\sup A_{m}$ means nothing in a general metric space. It is enough to simply obeserve that if $A_{m}\subset A_{n}$, then $$d(A_{m})=\sup_{x,y\in A_{m}}\rho(x,y)\leq\sup_{x,y\in A_{n}}\rho(x,y)=d(A_{n}).$$
- Third, you only need that $x_{m},x_{n}\in A_{N}$ to show that $$\rho(x_{m},x_{n})\leq d(A_{N}).$$
  Assuming wlog that $A_{m}\subset A_{n}$ is not required. (On that note, I assume you meant $\rho(x_{m},x_{n})=0$ instead of $|x_{m}-x_{n}|=0$.
- Finally for the last step of your proof I would suggest the following: So we find for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\{x_{n}\}_{n\geq N}$ is a sequence in $A_{N}$ converging to $x$. Since $A_{N}$ is closed it follows that $x\in A_{N}$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for these very helpful comments. If you wouldn't mind me asking a follow-up: I am still a bit unsure on when to use the standard absolute value metric and when to use the more general $\rho(x,y)$. Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The absolute value refers (in general) to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ acting as a Euclidean norm. When working with real or complex numbers you can use it with no problem. When working in normed space or a metric space most people will use the norm $\|\cdot\|$ or metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ notation instead of the absolute values. (Though I've seen professional mathematicians use absolute value instead of a metric. I tend to disagree with their choice of notation.)

Comment: Is it fair to say here that since $\sup A$ means nothing in a general metric space $R$ that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} D(A_n)$ also means nothing, so this assumption would need to be thought of in terms of the standard Euclidean metric?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider the set $A_{n}=[0,\frac{1}{n}]\times[0,\frac{1}{n}]$, this is a square between $(0,0)$, $(1/n,0)$, $(1/n,1/n)$ and $(0,1/n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. What is the supremum of $A_n$. A supremum denotes the smallest upper bound of $A_{n}$, but without an order defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (and one can define multiple partial orders on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) you cannot speak of an upper bound of $A_{n}$. You can speak of limits of sequences in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in terms of a metric or norm. $D(A_{n})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is just a real number and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}D(A_n)=0$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much for all of your help.